# How to build the MySQL query to search keyword having "$"?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I am having difficulty using the regular expression to search for a keyword (whole word match).

Each of these keyword is preceded by "$". Here is the query I am using for whole word match.

```
select * from users where code REGEXP '[[:<:]]ABCD[[:>:]]'
```

I am trying to find $ABCD in the users table.

Any idea, how to improve the MySQL query?

Comment: Does `\\$ABCD[[:>:]]` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take our word boundary from left and use `\\$`:

```
select * from users where code REGEXP '\\$ABCD[[:>:]]'
```

`$` is also considered a non-word character hence you cannot have a word boundary character after `$`.

Answer (score 0):

$ is a symbol with special meaning,
which is like "this is the end of the word".

Use \$ to use it as just a symbol